# Forming a negation of a statement (∀x∈A)(∀y∈B)((x=y)⇒(y>2))

Tags: logic

I have a statement from which I need to form a negation.
$$(\forall x \in A)(\forall y \in B)((x=y)\to (y>2))$$

Could this solution be correct?
$(\exists x \in A)(\exists y \in B)((x=y)\land(y\leq 2))$
or could it be solved like this
$(\exists x \notin A)(\exists y \notin B)((x=y)\land(y\leq 2))$ or $¬(\exists x \in A)(\exists y \in B)((x=y)\land(y\leq 2))$
as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is telling:

If **any** two elements $x$ living in $A$ and $y$ living in $B$ are equal, then $y$ will be greater than $2$.

The negation is:

**There are** two elements $x$ living in $A$ and $y$ living in $B$ that are equal **and** $y$ is **not** greater than $2$.

That's why I think: only your first answer is correct.

We can write $$(\forall x \in A)(\forall y \in B)((x=y)\to (y>2))$$ by [the rule of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) as

$$ (\forall x \in A)(\forall y \in B)(\neg(x=y)\lor (y>2))$$
Then the negation changes $$\forall x,\forall y,\neg (x=y) \lor (y>2)$$ to $$\exists x,\exists y,\neg\neg(x=y) \land (y\leq2)$$

and by [the double negation elemenation rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation) $\neg\neg(x=y)\Rightarrow (x=y) $. That's why the negation is:

$$(\exists x \in A)(\exists y \in B)((x=y)\land (y \leq 2))$$

also have a look [here](https://www.math.toronto.edu/preparing-for-calculus/3_logic/we_3_negation.html)

Statement $\rightarrow$    Negation

"A or B" $\rightarrow$ "not A and not B"

"A and B"   $\rightarrow$ "not A or not B"

"if A, then B" $\rightarrow$   "A and not B"

"For all x, A(x)" $\rightarrow$    "There exist x such that not A(x)"

"There exists x such that A(x)" $\rightarrow$  "For every x, not A(x)"

Comment: thank you, so you also assume that the last negation I wrote is incorrect?

Comment: in the last negation $¬(\exists x \in A)(\exists y \in B)((x=y)\land(y\leq 2))$ the first $\neg$ sign is unnecessary